# How can I convert every pixel that is not black to a certain color?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want every pixel that is not black to be set to white (or any arbitrary color).

I need this in Python (preferably using PIL, but other libraries can also be considered)

Thanks

Comment: You who clicked on the "close" link, why don't you explain to me why you did that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys

from PIL import Image

imin = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
imout = Image.new("RGB", imin.size)

imout.putdata(map(
                  lambda pixel: (0,0,0) if pixel == (0,0,0) else (255,255,255),
                  imin.getdata()
                 )
             ) 

imout.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Image.blend()`. Suppose your image is `im`.

```
# conversion matrix: any color to white, black to black
mtx = (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
mask = im.convert("L", mtx) # show() it to get the idea
decal = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (0, 0, 255)) # we fill with blue
Image.blend(im, decal, mask).show() # all black turned blue
```

This must be way faster than per-pixel lambda calls, especially on large images.

Answer (score 2):

using PIL

```
c   = color_of_choice
out = im.point(lambda i: c if i>0 else i)
```

Comment: I don't know why (I'm new to Python), but I had to change your code to  im.point(lambda i: c if i>(0,0,0) else i) .Otherwise it didn't detect the color difference.

Comment: @DanC that must be because i is a tuple, not an int.

Comment: @DanC My code was an example to illustrate how it'll work. It's for a 1-channel image (grayscale). For RGB, you need 3 channels hence the tuple !